# ORA-01791 on Hibernate Query

Tags: sql, hibernate

My code is:

```
Criteria criteriaA = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(entityA.class, "aaa");
Criteria criteriaB = criteriaA.createCriteria("entityB").setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); // It seems that the result transformer don't affect the code...

criteriaA.add( -- some restriction --)

if (orderById) {
    criteriaB.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
}

if (!orderById && orderByDate) {
    criteriaB.addOrder(Order.desc("date"));
}

criteriaA.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("entityB")));
```

entityA and entityB have a oneToMany relationshiop (one entityB may have 0..* entityA) but I can navigate only to A from B (project restrictions.. cannot change that).
Now, the problem is that I need no duplicate in the results returned, and I need to sort my result.
The strange fact is that the ORA-01791 (that tells me that there's an incorrect orderby) I launched only when sorting by date, sorting by id don't gave me any problem but both are property of the entity I want to distinct!
Why I can sort by id but not by date??
Is there another way to do what I'm trying to do?

---- EDIT -----
As maby suggested I looked at the generated query:

```
DEBUG [org.hibernate.SQL]
select distinct this_.BBB_ID as y0_
from TB_ENTITY_A this_ 
inner join TB_ENTITY_B entityB_ on this_.BBB_ID=entityB_.BBB_ID 
where this_.ANOTHER_ID=? and lower(this_.AAA_VALUE) like ? and this_.AAA_ID in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
order by entityB_.BBB_DATE asc
```

so, my distinct where applied only on the id of the foreign key..
How could I force Hibernate to select all the field?
If I do:

```
criteriaB.list();
```

instead of

```
criteriaA.list():
```

will I lose the filter from criteriaA?
I was thinking also to try to set in Projection all the field from the entityB but I'm not sure hibernate can convert the result to the entity.

Comment: +1 for the solution, was going to suggest a subselect myself. You can put that as answer to yourself, too.

Comment: Right, now I've done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mabi suggested I reply to my questions to post my solution:

---- SOLVED -----

I changed the way I was organizing the query: I've create a detached criteria for the many-side entity and retrieve the other entity with a subquery:

```
DetachedCriteria criteriaA = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EntityA.class, "aaa");
criteriaA.add( -- some restriction --);
criteriaA.setProjection(Projections.property("entityB"));

Criteria criteriaB = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(EntityB.class, "bbb");
criteriaB.add(Property.forName("id").in(criteriaA));
```

so I don't need a distinct and can sort for all the field i want from entity B.

Answer (score 2):

http://ora-01791.ora-code.com/ says:

> In this context, all ORDER BY items must be constants, SELECT list
>   expressions, or expressions whose operands are constants or SELECT
>   list expressions

I hazard a guess that you/hibernate don't select `date`. If you do, can you add the generated SQL to the question?

Comment: In regular cases it should work, however in this particular case by using DISTINCT the query planner don't know which one of the rows it will pick and therefore not being able to use the date as the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Strange problems occur when you use SQL keywords for table or field names. That's probably what happens here. Just try to put a `@Column(name = "date_")` on your entity attribute.

Comment: There was already:
    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "AAA_DATE", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
   @javax.persistence.Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public java.util.Date getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

Comment: I say also that all the entity attribute are annotated to the tables fields

Answer (score 0):

mabi is correct in his/her guess.

What you want to do is to produce a query that looks something like this:

```
select this_.BBB_ID as y0_, min(entityB_.BBB_DATE) as min_date
from TB_ENTITY_A this_ 
inner join TB_ENTITY_B entityB_ on this_.BBB_ID=entityB_.BBB_ID 
where this_.ANOTHER_ID=? and lower(this_.AAA_VALUE) like ? 
  and this_.AAA_ID in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
group by this_.BBB_ID
order by min_date asc
```

Don't know how to do it in Hibernate though.

If however Hibernate can't manage with two columns returned for fetching the ID, a query like this should work:

```
select y0_ 
    from(
        select this_.BBB_ID as y0_, min(entityB_.BBB_DATE) as min_date
            from TB_ENTITY_A this_ 
                inner join TB_ENTITY_B entityB_ on this_.BBB_ID=entityB_.BBB_ID 
            where this_.ANOTHER_ID=? and lower(this_.AAA_VALUE) like ? 
              and this_.AAA_ID in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            group by this_.BBB_ID
    ) a
order by min_date asc
```

But again, how to do it in Hibernate, I have no clue. It think it is possible to add custom SQL/HQL though, so you should be able to create it somehow.

Comment: But let's suppose to realize this query with hibernate, my doubt is: if in the first query hibernate use the ids returned to the query and recover the entity, if I made a query with id and date, could hibernate do the same?

Comment: Good question. I am not that proficient in Hibernate so I can't say

Comment: that's interesting, neither I know how to get such query, but I discovered that the results returned isn't typed, so with the add of the right projections to the criteria the command criteriaB.list() didn't throw any exception, but with the previous sql it was able to cast the object returned to the entityA, while with the projections trick the cast fails.

Comment: I was thinking about programmatically create a join to entityB from entityA, so my base criteria is setted to the entity i want to distinct